# Most common or vicious mistakes in C# development for experienced C++ programmers

Tags: c#, c++

What are the most common or vicious mistakes when experienced C++ programmers develop in C#?

Comment: Community wiki, perhaps? (PS - the "subjective and argumentative" closure vote, I'd disagree with. I don't think this question is likely to lead to argument! ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- the difference between `struct` and `class` in the two
- the difference between a `using` alias and a `typedef`
- when do my objects get collected? how do I destroy them *now*?
- how big is an `int`? (it is actually defined in C#)
- where's my linker? (actually, Mono does have a full AOT linker for some scenarios)

Comment: How big is an int.  The joys of a well defined language and environment :)

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that C++ leaves it implementation defined so that the compiler can use the most performant native type rather than being restricted by the specification. There are sized types available if you need that.

Comment: @Mark In C99 there is `stdint.h`. This is _not_ in standard C++ yet. (It is in tr1, but not implemented in MSVC 2008) See the wiki entry on stdint.h

Comment: @KitsuneYMG : Yes it's in the C standard, not the C++ one, that's why it's not supported in VS2008, even in their TR1. However it's in boost and it's header only, so it's not gonna make your exe any bigger ;)

Answer (score 13):

I've seen many C++ coders code in a COM style in C#, trying to deal with the inadequacies of the language.  C# provides lots of a type safe support for your enums and there are usually nicer APIs then P/Invoking back down to C++.

The other thing I've seen catch most people out is that C# generics are not templates.

Answer (score 11):

Calling `GC.Collect`.

Comment: +1. I have seen code where the programmer was so worried that his objects would stay in memory he called it continuously.

Answer (score 9):

1. Using **structs in favour for classes** all the time.
2. Using **in, out and ref** parameters all the time (This is a result of point 1).
3. Using **int values as error conditions** instead of using exceptions
4. Using the **virtual keyword instead of override** keyword.
5. Thinking that **char is an 8 bit signed value**.

Comment: The first three sound more like mistakes C programmers would make... or maybe very poor C++ programmers.

Comment: C++ programmers, like C programmers are used to think that using value types most times is fine.

Comment: #3 is equally wrong in C++ and C#; it looks more like something a C programmer would do in any of those languages.

Comment: Re #3: "Return codes considered harmful"?  I'm sorry, but if you need to collect intermediate results and need to keep going exceptions are a no-no. Enum return codes have their place.  Having try catches to control the "regular" flow is not the greatest idea.

Answer (score 5):

Thinking that "garbage collection" = "I never have to worry about object lifetime at all". For instance, opening a `FileStream` and forgetting to close it.

Or:

1. Allocating a lot of objects
2. Putting them in a big global dictionary (usually after "I know, I'll make a cache")
3. Wondering why the application's memory usage always goes up and never down ("but it's supposed to garbage collect!")

Comment: Doesn't `FileStream` close in its destructor like `fstream`?

Comment: @henle: You don't know when the destructor will be called, so it's better to call dispose, manually or via using semantics.

Comment: Well, in C++, you are sure that the destructor will be called as soon as the variable gets out of scope, so there is usually no need to explicitely dispose ressources (this is the point of RAII).

Comment: The `FileStream` finalizer gets called when the CLR needs to reclaim memory. If there's plenty memory free, then the `FileStream` may not get finalized until the program exits.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Destructors aren't called when they should? Isn't that a major problem?

Comment: .NET finalizers aren't the same as C++ destructors. If the cleanup code isn't critical then you can leave it to garbage collection time (finalization). If you do need deterministic cleanup -- like closing a file handle -- call `IDisposable.Dispose`.

Answer (score 5):

Confusing "pass by reference" and "reference type":

```
void GetAnArray(int input, ref string[] output);
```

(Compare with C++: `void getAnArray(int input, std::vector<std::string>& output);`)

Answer (score 4):

- RAII vs IDispose
- value type vs ref type (struct vs class, boxing and unboxing, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Writing the full namespace each time.

This is fine in C++ when you're typing `std::this` or `boost::that`. Not so great in C# when you repeat `System.Windows.Forms.Whatever` all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

Incidentally, the C# compiler has a number of heuristics in it for helping out the experienced C++ programmer who is a novice C# programmer. For example, if you say

```
int x[];
```

the compiler will helpfully point out that the [] is a part of the type in C#, so you probably meant

```
int[] x;
```

C# also allows things like putting unnecessary semicolons at the end of a class declaration so that C++ programmers who are in that habit don't get bitten by it.

Answer (score 3):

Forgetting to specify access modifiers for every class member.

Comment: @Judah Himango: What I mean is that in C++ you use labels for the different access zones. It's happened to me a lot that I forgot to write `public` before a method, because the previous methods were also public. And I see this happen all the time to C++ programmers learning C#.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to implement `const` correctness on `string`s.

Answer (score 2):

One that got me, and I believe a lot of non C++ people too, was leaking memory due to registered events keeping an object alive.

IDisposable grated to begin with (and still does if I'm honest) but was pretty obviously going to be a difference when going from native to managed code so it is not something I'd expect C++ developers to actually fall foul of, they just won't like it.

Answer (score 1):

using Hungarian Notation and other C++ naming conventions

```
private int m_iMyIntField;
class CWidget { ... }
```

Comment: Misused Hungarian Notation isn't particular to C++, and it's more an artifact of the WIN32 and MFC libraries.

Comment: you mean like IMyInterface or MyException?