# Bad C++ programmer behaviors in C#

Tags: c#, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most common or vicious mistakes in C# development for experienced C++ programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424807/most-common-or-vicious-mistakes-in-c-development-for-experienced-c-programmers)

I'm a long time C++ programmer about to start working on C# projects.

What are some conceptual changes to be aware of, and most importantly, what should I avoid doing in C# that I would normally do in C++? What bad habits do C++ programmers bring to C# that they should lose?

I have a list of C# books I intend to read.  I'd like to augment that with experiences from other programmers that have made this same transition because I'll probably tend to make the same errors they did; I'd like to prevent that before it happens.

Comment: How about the conceptual change that they are different languages? The bad habit is trying to guess-program C# because you know C++. C++ isn't C#. **Get a beginner C# book so you can learn beginner C#.** That's all. If you could program C# because you can program C++, they wouldn't be different languages.

Comment: @Gman +1 Yes, there is an assumption in this question that programming ability in one will carry over to the other. I'm mainly a vb.net programmer (go on, have a good laugh :D) and if I'd gone straight from vb6 to .net without learning the basics/fundamental changes then I would have written some *awful* .net code!

Comment: @GMan: I do intend to treat it as a separate language. My concern is over nuances in the language features that may trip me up. For example the distinction between structs and classes in c# that Tergiver pointed out. I'm hoping to gain from others' experiences.

Comment: @JoshD: The thing is that you'd learn that in a book. You need to forget you know other languages when you learn a new one.

Comment: @GMan: I understand that (I do have a list of books to read). But what about the language concepts I know? What about the design patterns I know? I'd like to leverage my knowledge rather than learning over from 'what is a variable?' I don't know of a specific book that lists the typical errors c++ coders make when switching to c#. That's what I'm after because if others have made these mistakes, it's likely I will to, and I'd like to reduce the risk of those common mistakes. (I also thought this might be a generally useful question, too.)

Comment: @JoshD: It'll take you one chapter to get past "what is a variable?". And even that's not necessarily the same. And what about language concepts you know? Do you not see how that makes no sense? You don't know the language so how could you possibly know any language concepts?! Design patterns are of little use as well, because not all "patterns" (the term is crap anyway) translate or are even necessary. What you're effectively saying is "I know English and I want to learn Latin. I don't want to have to relearn what a letter is." Okay, that's fine, but there's more then letters to a language.

Comment: This should be community wiki...

Comment: @GMan: If I'm not mistaken, it is possible for two languages to have a non-empty intersection of features. That is how I could possibly know a concept without knowing the language. (By concepts I mean things such as classes, inheritance, templates, and the like.) If you feel this question has no worth, that is fine, but you are not being helpful with your comments.

Comment: Of course, with Latin, you do have a bit to learn about letters since there are only 23 of them (in classical Latin). :-) Anyway, the problem isn't learning how to write code in a given language; it's usually quite easy to stumble through and write mediocre, working code in any language. The problem is learning how to write idiomatic, high-quality, maintainable, elegant code in a new language. Idiomatic C# has very little in common with idiomatic C++.

Comment: @Josh: Sorry if I'm not coming across as helpful. But @James caught what I'm trying to say. You're just going to end up being a bad C# programmer if you're thinking about C++ the whole time. Just like you'd be a bad Latin speaker if you thought about how you'd be doing the same thing in English.

Comment: Duplicate: [Most common or vicious mistakes in c# development for experienced c++ programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424807/most-common-or-vicious-mistakes-in-c-development-for-experienced-c-programmers)

Comment: @GMan: I think I'm not very clear in my writing (I could use a refresher in good English :-) ), and I misrepresented myself. Sorry about that. I completely agree with you and @James on this. I see all too often people at my job "thinking in C" when they should be thinking in c++. And I endeavor to think in c# without letting c++ get in my way and clouding things. Thank you for your comments and for clearing up my confusion about your meaning.

Comment: @GMan: "If you could program C# because you can program C++, they wouldn't be different languages." -- then they mustn't be different languages... I really had no problem switching over to C#, but I also had a number of other languages under my belt (perhaps Java shares a few more concepts than C++ does)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just one example:

In C++ there is no difference between a struct and a class. Over the years this has led groups and individuals to define their own rules for using one over the other.

In C# there is a concrete difference. A struct is a value type and a class is a reference type.

When C++ programmers bring thier old, arbitrary class/struct definitions to C#, unexpected things tend to happen.

Here is a fairly good read for C++ programmers moving to C#:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx

Comment: They do behave differently, but the compiler usually yells at you when you've used them incorrectly, no? It's usually not a run-time error? At least in my experience...

Comment: Just the fact that a class is reference type and a struct is a value type will cause unintended issues, such as when you pass it into a method and are expecting the original object to be modified.  It also can easily bloat the memory usage due to all the unintended copying.  These issues won't be caught at compile or run-time, and have to be manually debugged.

Answer (score 8):

One thing to be aware of is that C# doesn't have destructors in the same sense as C++ does. A method with the signature of a C++ destructor is called a finalizer in C# and it's not necessary (and in some cases not recommended) to implement those.

Check out the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interfaceand these articles on garbage collection: [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx) and [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx).

Comment: I wonder how hard it would have been for Microsoft to have added something analogous to a "Using" tag to the declaration of an iDisposable field, to indicate that the field should be ".disposed" when the object itself is.  Otherwise it is difficult to ensure the disposal of iDisposable objects that are created via initializations (rather than in the constructor).

Comment: Actually it is called a **destructor** in the C# world. For worse.

Comment: +1 for a very interesting read!

Answer (score 7):

- there is no implicit RAII, you have to explicitly code it
- there is no const protection
- properties are pairs of methods, not a value
- when iterating you start before collection and end at the end of it (in terms of C++)
- foreach is like using const_iterator
- List as the name says, is not a list, is a an array
- generics are resolved at their compile time, not at time of using them

Answer (score 3):

Worst I have **seen** is

1) overly using Critical Context (locking using **Monitor or lock**() statement) in a web project! Result quite often is reducing IIS to a more-or-less single-threaded system.

2) Too much string processing. Used to do everything themselves so not relying on framework. **Strings are immutable in C# while they are not in C++.**

3) Using **unsafe** code because they can and not because they should.

4) **Not trusting GC**

Comment: -1 because 1, 2, 3 are true for C++ good style too. 4) is wrong. You really can't always trust it. Member system resources are an example.

Comment: "4) is wrong. You really can't always trust it."

Didn't I say?? :)

Comment: @Aliostad: *please* read my answer and give me as elegant solution as C++ gives.

Comment: Yeah... you can trust the GC, until you can't of course, and then you have no clue how to fix your problem because you trusted it implicitly for so long.

Comment: @Ed come on Ed,you cannot be serious GC works. It works for Java, works for C#, and all those dynamic languages out there. I actually have done fair bit of C++ doing heavy image processing and I managed my memory alright, never had leaks but coding in C# is less coding thanks to .NET Fx.

Comment: how are 1 and 2 specific to C++ programmers?

Comment: Jalf Didn't you see what I wrote: "I have seen"... but generally C++ coders will use locking more since they are already aware of multi-threading while average C# coder is not.

Answer (score 3):

The big ones:

- C# doesn't have multiple inheritance,
  it uses interfaces instead.
- You can't control the lifetime of an
  object or use that to your advantage.
- The C# equality operator doesn't
  always do what you think it should.
  Sometimes it compares the content of
  a variable and sometimes the address
  of the variable.

Comment: You can, and absolutely must control the lifetime of objects in a GC environment. Mind your references!

Comment: Removing all references doesn't mean the end of an objects life, unless you force GC.  This is why you also have IDisposable and using to clean up other resources faster.  The control of the lifetime is alot looser.

Comment: @Greg: There's nothing wrong with your logic. What I object to is the attitude of complacency. From your application's point of view, an object is dead and gone when it no longer holds a reference. A garbage collector is a simulation of a system with infinite memory. The problem is that it is only a simulation and we know that there isn't infinite memory. That means that we are still responsible for object lifetime.

Comment: @Greg part 2: IDisposable and the lifetime control of external resources are a different subject altogether.

Comment: @Tergiver: I agree but I was trying to make a different point. In C++ I can use scope to cause object destruction. I can use that to my advantage. One example is a class that changes the cursor to an hourglass and restores it in the destructor. Or the example here http://jaysprenkle.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/managing-critical-sections-using-scope-in-c/

Comment: And in C# you don't have to use scope to cause object destruction. You only have to make it unreachable, and the GC will clean it up when it runs. In many cases this can be before the end of the current scope is reached.

Leaving the scope (pun intended) of C#, this is clearest in functional languages with tail recursion as the primary looping construct. You can have a program which tail-recurses forever without ever reaching an end-of-scope, but it will still get garbage collected.

Comment: The only issue is it's unpredictable when garbage collection happens. If you want behavior when it's destroyed you predict when it will happen

Answer (score 2):

Not much, moving from C++ to C# is a sort of degradation, so you can't do "Bad things". The only thing I can think of is relying on automatic memory management:

```
class A {
    ofstream file;
public:
    // bla bla
};
```

In C# you need to implement all the IDisposable garbage to not leak the file... You can easily forget it.

Bad C# programmer behaviors in C++ would be a more interesting topic.

Comment: If you correctly implement it (IDisposable+Finalizer) then even if you forget, GC will kick in - although it will not be immediate. If you are supposed to forget, in C++ there are so many things you will forget! All those memories you have to release manually...

Comment: @Aliostad: implementing IDisposable won't much. If you loose A GC will close file anyway, even without IDisposable. But it may never happen. Unlike C# I don't release memory (or other resources) manually in C++. Heard about RAII? It solves almost all the problems, at least much more than GC does.

Comment: Yeah really, I don't get it. All the pro-GC people, you really think that most of my resources are memory? Most of them are external resources or memory objects representing external resources. Those resources must be freed in deterministic fashion.

Comment: @Aliostad: there's no guarantee that the finalizer will ever run.

Comment: @jalf If you need guarantee, then you use CriticalFinalizerObject.

Comment: moving the goalposts. :) My point was simply that if you implement IDisposable+ finalizer, the GC is *not* guaranteed to kick in. Sure, you can work around that if you're willing to plow through those 2 pages of additional requirements and constraints in order to make your code a CER so you can use a CriticalFinalizerObject so you can be sure the finalizer will run.......... but really... That's hardly the same as "correctly implemneting IDisposable+Finalizer" which was the starting point.

Answer (score 2):

There's stuff you can do in C++ that you can't do in C#, and vice versa.  They aren't likely to cause you problems.

Biggest change - getting rid of the "instantiation is initialization" mindset.  Garbage collection means you don't need to worry about allocating or freeing memory (except when you do), but it also means you can't rely on something falling out of scope triggering the destructor to clean up after you.

Learn the "using" construct, in C#, and make sure you use it.

Second change - in C++ "class" and "struct" are effectively synonyms.  In C#, they are very different things.

Comment: A "using" block provides something analogous to C++ behavior of disposing resources when the block exits.  Unfortunately, there's no way to tag fields for automatic disposal when an object itself is disposed, nor is there any pleasant way of cleaning up an object whose initialization fails.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a "bad" habit, but something you definitely need to keep in mind when switching from C++ to C#: *relying on destructors to do your cleanup.* Instead, you need to remember to implement `IDisposable` and control your object's lifetime by a `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Things to change when moving from C++ to C#:

- Use properties when possible to represent class member data
- Use interfaces in situations that might call for multiple inheritance in C++
- Use events for notification instead of handing callback functions (delegates) to classes
- Remember to use the using() {} construct to ensure that resources like files and DB connections are disposed when they go out of scope.

That's just off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

The biggest shift for me was to stop worrying about freeing memory, thread safety (I mean you still have to lock things, but C# is designed for threading from day 1 so there are no nasty gotchas) and header files.

If you feel tempted to use /unsafe you are almost certainly wrong.

Learn the class library.